# Printing parts that inlay in other parts...clearance

Tags: modeling

I will try and explain this the best way I can.

I have the letter "T", and I want to print a white letter T and have a red letter T inlaid inside of that.  How can I make the inlay smaller, without "scaling" it?  Scaling it will make it smaller, but then it wont line up.  I need to take say 2 mm off of the outside dimension of the letter.  The white letter would have a 2 mm wall around the void on top, then I can print a red T to fit inside that void.

So my question in a nut shell is this.  How can I make clearance with out using scale or change the dimensions?  I realize the dimensions will change removing the 2 mm, but that is different than changing the x and y dimensions, because that will change the whole letter.  I just want to take off 2 mm off the outside.

I cant find info, or at least I cant word my questions right to find what I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe show how your T looks like? and even share it: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/  What you're looking for might the Shrink Fatten function (alt S)

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for.  I guess I just wasn't wording my searches right.  I was using the letter T as an example, my part is more complex and that is why the scaling wasn't working, but I just tested the shrink/fatten and that is it.  Thanks again....

Comment: Also check the options in the operator box (bottom left of your 3d view)